# Laravel - phpunit how to add some comments?

Tags: laravel, unit-testing

I am learning the testing of my laravel application , with phpunit.

All works fine but I would like the ouputs given be more clear.

For example for my tests I have this return :

[image]

How to have this : 
- test "myFirstTest' : OK
- test "MySecondTest" : OK

Is it possible to add some comments in my scripts , something like that :

```
    public function testPageErreurConnexion()
    {

        $this->visit('login')
        ->type('59414552', 'compte')
        ->type('toto', 'password')
        ->press('btn_connexion')
        ->seePageIs('login')
        ->see('Impossible')
        ->addComments('this is a comment');

    }
```

As you see I am a very beginner about these tests.

Comment: Try this: ```php phpunit.phar --coverage-html tests/TestAuthentication.php```. If that doesn't work try adding directory in between ```--coverage-html``` and ```tests/...```. That should create an HTML file with output closer to what you are after. See [phpunit docs](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/textui.html#textui.clioptions) for more information.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's excatly what I was looking for. Merci